# Remove Customer Welcome Message in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I found the switch to remove/edit the guest welcome message fairly easy but have not been so lucky with the customer logged in welcome message.

I have searched all over and have found nothing.  Would someone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What does the message says?

Answer (score 3):

From your question it is not clear that, whether you are using any custom theme for your website. However I have a strong feeling that, you are using a custom theme. In default `rwd/default` theme I dont think such welcome message does exist ! (May be I am wrong :)).

When a customer login into a page, he will taken to dashboard page. The action for this looks like `customer/account/index`. Layout handle corresponding to this action is `customer_account_index`. So any template comes under this layout handle is in hot spot. But the good starting point would be `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/customer/account/dashboard.phtml`. I pointed out this template because, it is a kind of parent template for this action. This template constitutes dashboard content.

So my assumption is that, either this template holds that "welcome" message directly. Or it may hold that block which generates that welcome message as like this

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome_block_alias');
```

`welcome_blocks_alias` is a block which comes inside `customer_account_index` layout handle. (it comes as an `as` property of a block). So find that block and find out which template that holds by that block.(It will specify in `template` property ). Open that template and remove it.

So using this info, please dig more. You can definitely find it.

Note: You can find the layout handle `customer_account_index` inside `customer.xml` file at `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/layout/customer.xml`